# Level selection view - similiar to Angry Bird's

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol, springboard

I am making game and need to prepare view for level selection. Could you recommend me some opensource library which could I use? I need icons to vibrate after long pressing one of them, some callbacks after choosing them, possibility to prepare custom icon's view, page control and horizontal scrolling. I was trying to use OpenSpringBoard but weirdly couldn't see scrollview and pagecontrol working in this project - it seems that there's possibility to use only one page. On the other hand, myLauncher(https://github.com/dlinsin/myLauncher) isn't so easy to include in project, as I need a seperate view with some delegate methods.

I need to be compatible with >iOS 4.2

[image: Angry Birds]

Comment: You might like to post this question in gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BobSort Just FYI, "which technology to use" questions aren't a good fit for gamedev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this project??

https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView

You can use this within every Page Control View. Just you need to modified according to your business.